# Get data from last 3 days from NASA API

Tags: api

I am using api.nasa.gov and trying to get data from last three days. But I cannot find what should I add in the url. Cannot find the option to filter out the result.

Can anyone help me out?

This is the url I am using

```
$url = "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/browse?page=0&size=50&api_key=api_key";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docs on the website state

[documentation](https://api.nasa.gov/api.html#neows-feed)

prop **start_date**

prop **end_date**

https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2015-09-07&end_date=2015-09-08&api_key=DEMO_KEY

GL :)!